# Java service wrapper - application doesn't execute when service starts

Tags: java, windows-services, java-service-wrapper

I have an application called "Update.jar" that I'm trying to use with the java service wrapper (JSW), but  when I start the service (either from SERVICES.MSC or StartUpdate-NT.bat) the application doesn't run, even though the service is showing as started in SERVICES.MSC. There should be an icon displayed in the system tray through out the length of the runtime.

I've successfully launched the app:

- by executing the .jar
- by running Update.bat in [wrapper]/bin/ directory
- by executing from the command line

Below is my wrapper.conf file:

```
#encoding=UTF-8
# Configuration files must begin with a line specifying the encoding
#  of the the file.

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper License Properties (Ignored by Community Edition)
#********************************************************************
# Professional and Standard Editions of the Wrapper require a valid
#  License Key to start.  Licenses can be purchased or a trial license
#  requested on the following pages:
# http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/purchase
# http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/trial

# Include file problems can be debugged by removing the first '#'
#  from the following line:
#include.debug

# The Wrapper will look for either of the following optional files for a
#  valid License Key.  License Key properties can optionally be included
#  directly in this configuration file.
#include ../conf/wrapper-license.conf
#include ../conf/wrapper-license-%WRAPPER_HOST_NAME%.conf

# The following property will output information about which License Key(s)
#  are being found, and can aid in resolving any licensing problems.
#wrapper.license.debug=TRUE

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Localization
#********************************************************************
# Specify the locale which the Wrapper should use.  By default the system
#  locale is used.
#wrapper.lang=en_US # en_US or ja_JP

# Specify the location of the Wrapper's language resources.  If these are
#  missing, the Wrapper will default to the en_US locale.
wrapper.lang.folder=../lang

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Java Properties
#********************************************************************
# Java Application
#  Locate the java binary on the system PATH:
wrapper.java.command=java
#  Specify a specific java binary:
#set.JAVA_HOME=/java/path
#wrapper.java.command=%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java

# Tell the Wrapper to log the full generated Java command line.
#wrapper.java.command.loglevel=INFO

# Java Main class.  This class must implement the WrapperListener interface
#  or guarantee that the WrapperManager class is initialized.  Helper
#  classes are provided to do this for you.  See the Integration section
#  of the documentation for details.
wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp update.Tray


# Java Classpath (include wrapper.jar)  Add class path elements as
#  needed starting from 1
wrapper.java.classpath.1=../lib/wrapper.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=../lib/Update.jar




# Java Library Path (location of Wrapper.DLL or libwrapper.so)
wrapper.java.library.path.1=../lib

# Java Bits.  On applicable platforms, tells the JVM to run in 32 or 64-bit mode.
wrapper.java.additional.auto_bits=TRUE

# Java Additional Parameters
wrapper.java.additional.1=

# Initial Java Heap Size (in MB)
#wrapper.java.initmemory=3

# Maximum Java Heap Size (in MB)
#wrapper.java.maxmemory=64

# Application parameters.  Add parameters as needed starting from 1
#wrapper.app.parameter.1=update.Tray

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Logging Properties
#********************************************************************
# Enables Debug output from the Wrapper.
# wrapper.debug=TRUE

# Format of output for the console.  (See docs for formats)
wrapper.console.format=PM

# Log Level for console output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.console.loglevel=INFO

# Log file to use for wrapper output logging.
wrapper.logfile=../logs/wrapper.log

# Format of output for the log file.  (See docs for formats)
wrapper.logfile.format=LPTM

# Log Level for log file output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.logfile.loglevel=INFO

# Maximum size that the log file will be allowed to grow to before
#  the log is rolled. Size is specified in bytes.  The default value
#  of 0, disables log rolling.  May abbreviate with the 'k' (kb) or
#  'm' (mb) suffix.  For example: 10m = 10 megabytes.
wrapper.logfile.maxsize=0

# Maximum number of rolled log files which will be allowed before old
#  files are deleted.  The default value of 0 implies no limit.
wrapper.logfile.maxfiles=0

# Log Level for sys/event log output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.syslog.loglevel=NONE

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper General Properties
#********************************************************************
# Allow for the use of non-contiguous numbered properties
wrapper.ignore_sequence_gaps=TRUE

# Title to use when running as a console
wrapper.console.title=Test Wrapper Sample Application

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper JVM Checks
#********************************************************************
# Detect DeadLocked Threads in the JVM. (Requires Standard Edition)
wrapper.check.deadlock=TRUE
wrapper.check.deadlock.interval=10
wrapper.check.deadlock.action=RESTART
wrapper.check.deadlock.output=FULL

# Out Of Memory detection.
# (Ignore output from dumping the configuration to the console.  This is only needed by the TestWrapper sample application.)
wrapper.filter.trigger.999=wrapper.filter.trigger.*java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
wrapper.filter.allow_wildcards.999=TRUE
wrapper.filter.action.999=NONE
# (Simple match)
wrapper.filter.trigger.1000=java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
# (Only match text in stack traces if -XX:+PrintClassHistogram is being used.)
#wrapper.filter.trigger.1000=Exception in thread "*" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
#wrapper.filter.allow_wildcards.1000=TRUE
wrapper.filter.action.1000=RESTART
wrapper.filter.message.1000=The JVM has run out of memory.

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Email Notifications. (Requires Professional Edition)
#********************************************************************
# Common Event Email settings.
#wrapper.event.default.email.debug=TRUE
#wrapper.event.default.email.smtp.host=<SMTP_Host>
#wrapper.event.default.email.smtp.port=25
#wrapper.event.default.email.subject=[%WRAPPER_HOSTNAME%:%WRAPPER_NAME%:%WRAPPER_EVENT_NAME%] Event Notification
#wrapper.event.default.email.sender=<Sender email>
#wrapper.event.default.email.recipient=<Recipient email>

# Configure the log attached to event emails.
#wrapper.event.default.email.attach_log=TRUE
#wrapper.event.default.email.maillog.lines=50
#wrapper.event.default.email.maillog.format=LPTM
#wrapper.event.default.email.maillog.loglevel=INFO

# Enable specific event emails.
#wrapper.event.wrapper_start.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_prelaunch.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_start.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_started.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_deadlock.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_stop.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_stopped.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_restart.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_failed_invocation.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_max_failed_invocations.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_kill.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_killed.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_unexpected_exit.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.wrapper_stop.email=TRUE

# Specify custom mail content
wrapper.event.jvm_restart.email.body=The JVM was restarted.\n\nPlease check on its status.\n

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Windows NT/2000/XP Service Properties
#********************************************************************
# WARNING - Do not modify any of these properties when an application
#  using this configuration file has been installed as a service.
#  Please uninstall the service before modifying this section.  The
#  service can then be reinstalled.

# Name of the service
wrapper.name=Auto-update

# Display name of the service
wrapper.displayname=Auto-update

# Description of the service
wrapper.description=Auto-update

# Service dependencies.  Add dependencies as needed starting from 1
wrapper.ntservice.dependency.1=

# Mode in which the service is installed.  AUTO_START, DELAY_START or DEMAND_START
wrapper.ntservice.starttype=AUTO_START

# Allow the service to interact with the desktop.
wrapper.ntservice.interactive=true
```

Wrapper.log contents:

STATUS | wrapper  | 2011/08/10 10:31:56 | Auto-update service installed.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2011/08/10 10:32:07 | Starting the Auto-update service...
STATUS | wrapper  | 2011/08/10 10:32:07 | --> Wrapper Started as Service
STATUS | wrapper  | 2011/08/10 10:32:07 | Java Service Wrapper Community Edition 32-bit 3.5.10
STATUS | wrapper  | 2011/08/10 10:32:07 |   Copyright (C) 1999-2011 Tanuki Software, Ltd. All Rights Reserved.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2011/08/10 10:32:07 |     http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com
STATUS | wrapper  | 2011/08/10 10:32:07 | 
STATUS | wrapper  | 2011/08/10 10:32:08 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/08/10 10:32:08 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
STATUS | wrapper  | 2011/08/10 10:32:11 | Auto-update started.

Could someone please point me at the right direction?

Comment: Did you check the contents of a log file? (wrapper.logfile=../logs/wrapper.log)

Comment: Arturs, I've added the log contents to the description (apologies for it showing all squashed, I couldn't edit the markup for some reason)

Comment: We used Tanuki wrapper in one Java project I was on few years ago, and I remember we had some issues (all of them eventually solved). Hoped that log will show something significant, so I can only help with pointing questions. Do you have any other ways on how to check your Java program at least tries to get started (other than tray)? Have you tried logging exceptions in #main of your update.Tray? Have you tried writing some other very simple Java class that implements WrapperListener to prove that Java Service Wrapper works fine with the current infrastructure?

Comment: I have added a line of code at the start of the main class, that should pop up a blank error message as soon as application is launched. However the message doesn't get thrown when I run the service. I've also ran the test wrapper app and it was working fine, so I've a strong feeling the fault might be in my wrapper.conf file which I've changed several times but had no luck getting it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you set the loglevel to debug by setting
wrapper.debug=true

and rerun your application as service and post. From the log file you posted, your application seems to run... what happens after starting? does it shut down?

What OS are you running?
Please note that starting with Windows Vista, all Services run in an isolated desktop (session 0), since that, you wouldn't be able to see the tray icon in your user desktop...

Small correction (unrelated to your problem), also please change in your conf file:

```
wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp update.Tray
```

to

```
wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
wrapper.app.parameter.1=update.Tray
```

cheers,

Comment: I am running it on windows 7, so this must be why I'm not seeing any output on the screen. That means this is not an issue with the JSW - I'll need to run the interface separate from the windows service. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!